# reduce return breaks from paragraph in php

Tags: php, preg-replace

here is the variable :

```
$letexts = "Hello this is a sample


after 2 return breaks there is ...



another 3 return breaks";
```

As you can see there are 2 return breaks and then after that 3 return breaks.
I would like to be able to have this results:

```
echo $letexts;
```

will display:

```
Hello this is a sample

after 2 return breaks there is ...

another 3 return breaks
```

I used all of these and NONE worked so it got me pulling my hair:

```
$letexts = preg_replace("/\r\n\s*\r\n/", "\r\n", $letexts);
$letexts = str_replace(array("\r", "\n", "\r\n"), "\r\n", $letexts);
$letexts = trim($letexts);
$letexts = preg_replace('~[\r\n]~','',$letexts);
```

any suggestions please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display in html.

Use the function [nl2br](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php).

Comment: I don't know if this will solve the problem of multiple lines in the rendered HTML.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid You have to replace multiple newline code to one first.

Comment: @xdazz what do you mean? more details please

Comment: @xdazz thanks that worked! , nl2br , then str replace the br tags

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$letexts = preg_replace("/[\r\n]{3,}/", "\r\n\r\n", $letexts);
```

Comment: Try removing all references to `\r` and see what happens

Comment: To remove all of them you can use a variation of your example `$letexts = str_replace(array("\r", "\n", "\r\n"), "", $letexts);`